# When adding a custom REST endpoint, where do you put the endpoint function, and where do you put the function registration call?

Tags: customization, ajax, rest-api

WordPress documentation, bloggers, and StackExchange answerers have done a great job of describing the code you write to make a custom REST endpoint, but I cannot find any documentation that describes exactly *WHERE* you place the code.

Say I have an endpoint that I want to return the string "foo". From my reading, I implement a function like this:

```
function my_foo() {
    return "foo";
}
```

and I register the function with a call like this:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'mycompany/v1', '/foo/', array(
            'methods' => 'GET',
            'callback' => 'my_foo'
    ) );
} )
```

There is nothing difficult about this, but for the life of me I cannot figure out WHERE to put these.

For the REST endpoint, I assume I would put the function inside a file at:

```
wp-json/mycompany/v1/foo.php
```

but it would be nice to know for sure.

As for the `add_action()` call I am also having a bear of a time finding out where the call goes.

The documentation [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/) fails to describe where these calls should live, as does the article [here](https://tomjn.com/2017/01/23/writing-wp-rest-api-endpoint-2-minutes/) (and many other sources I have found).

If anybody could point out where these locations are documented, or that I'm missing something right in front, that would be great!

Comment: You should create a plugin. Check out the [Plugin Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/) for help on how to create a plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are developing a theme, the proper place to put your code in this case if your theme's `functions.php` file. This is the file that is surely going to be run when your website is being accessed.

If you are developing a plugin, you can put your code inside a php file (like `foo.php`) and then include/require it in your template, whichever suits your needs.

Don't save or alter ANY file outside the `wp-content` folder, or your plugins. These are going to be overridden by WordPress updates, and have a chance to be identified as malware by some anti-malware plugins/server apps.

You can actually put your code directly inside your plugin's core file, but i prefer to categorize the functions in case i need to access or modify them quickly later (personal opinion).